# Not getting expected output from this code using logical operators and pre/post increment

Tags: c, logical-operators, post-increment, pre-increment

I am not getting expected output in the following C code

```
main(){
    int i=0,j=-2,k=0,m;

    if((!i||--j&&k++)&&(i++||j++&&!k++))
    {
        printf("i=%d j=%d k=%d",i,j,k);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output in compiler as :

```
i=1 j=-1 k=1
```

But I don't understand what exactly is going on here.

I think the if statement should not run since its argument is false

Note the first bracket     `(!i||--j&&k++)`

here as `!i=1` hence this bracket is true since anything with 1 under OR operator will be true.

out values become:    `i=0, j=-3, k=1`

Now notice the second bracket:    `(i++||j++&&!k++)`

Here we have `( 0 || -3 && !1) = 0, false`

as the brackets are separated by `&&`, the whole argument of if statement becomes `false`.

Please explain me where my argument is wrong. I am a new to C

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198974/discussion-on-question-by-abhay-not-getting-expected-output-from-this-code-using).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s spread this out a little to make reading it easier:

```
int i = 0, j = -2, k=0, m;

(!i || --j && k++) && (i++ || j++ && !k++)
```

As you note `!i` is true (value 1), so the `||` is true. The `||` operator is defined not to evaluate its right operand if the left operand is true, so `--j && k++` is not evaluated and has no effect. (The right operand is `--j && k++` because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so `A || B && C` is structured as `A || (B && C)`.)

That settles the left operand of the central `&&`. In the right operand, `i++` increments `i` to 1 but evaluates to the current value of `i`, 0, so it is false for the purposes of the `||` operator. So the right operand of that `||` is evaluated.

That operand is `j++ && !k++`. Since `j` is −2, `j++` changes `j` to −1 and evaluates to −2, which is a value of true for the purposes of `&&`. Then `k++` increments `k` to 1 but evaluates to 0, and `!k++` changes this to 1, yielding true for the `&&` and therefore true for the previous `||` and the central `&&`.

At this point `i` is 1, `j` is −1, and `k` is 1, which is the result you got.

Answer (score 6):

The logical AND operator `&&` and the logical OR operator `||` are short circuit operators, meaning that the right side won't be evaluated if the result of the expression can be determined from the left side.

So when this subexpression runs:

```
(!i||--j&&k++)
```

Which is parsed as:

```
(!i||(--j&&k++))
```

The left side of the `||` evaluates to true, so `--j&&k++` is not evaluated, meaning the value of `j` remains -2 and the value of `k` remains 0.

So the left side of the outermost `&&` is true, so now we evaluate the right side:

```
(i++||j++&&!k++)
```

Which is parsed as:

```
(i++||(j++&&!k++))
```

`i` is incremented to 1, then the old value is used in `||`.  The old value of 0 evaluates to false so the right side is evaluated.  `j` is incremented to -1 and the old value of -2 evaluates to true, so the right side of `&&` is evaluated.  `k` is incremented to 1 and the old value of 0 is applied to the `!` operator which evaluates to true.  This makes the entire expression true and the statement is printed, at which time `i` is 1, `j` is -1, and `k` is 1.

Answer (score 1):

you may be missing that if statements ends once they are satisfied, so `(!i||--j&&k++)` is only going to compute `i` and the other operations are going to be disregarded. By that I mean `j` is going to be -2 by the end of the first statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that. I had a feeling that this is what was happening here but had to post here to be sure. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would recommend the "fail fast" approach. Try creating a simple file and printing their values for smaller if statements.